# Expression Call Any Method Reverse

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, expression, any

I'm trying to write manually this linq sentence:

```
item => !item.Matches.Any(m => m.MarketPlace == "Amazon");
```

I know calling the Any method, but how do I do the reverse?

```
...
...
var anyCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { modelType }, models, lambdaExp); 
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(anyCall, item);
```

this code sql outputs 'Exists'. How to sql outputs 'Not Exists' ?

Comment: Do you mean `item.Matches.All(m => m.MarketPlace != "Amazon")`, which is logically the same?  If not what exactly do you mean by "reverse"?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write descriptive. I am looking for Any method using Expression Call. How can I do the reverse. Any sql output Exists. How can I write Not Exists?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One handy way of figuring out how to generate the expression trees you want, is to make a method that takes the signature as an expression, call it the way you want to use it, then inspect the argument in the debugger.  You can step through the entire tree of some really complex expressions this way and gain all kinds of insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context reverse makes me think of reordering. If you want to negate an expression you can do it like so:

```
var trueExpression = Expression.Constant(true);
var falseExpression = Expression.Not(trueExpression);
```

In debug view `falseExpression` is `!True`.

To answer your question:

```
var noneCall = Expression.Not(Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { modelType }, models, lambdaExp));
```

should do the trick.